# Multiple Uploads to website simultaneosly

Tags: upload

I am building a ASP.Net website and the website accepts a PDF as input and processes them. I am generating an intermediate file with a particular name. But I want to know if multiple users are using the same site at the same time, then how will the server handle this.

How can I handle this. Will Multi-Threading do the job? What about the file names of the intermediate files I am generating? How can I make sure they won't override each other. How to achieve performance?

Sorry if the question is too basic for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not into .NET but it sounds like a generic problem anyways, so here are my two cents.

Like you said, multithreading (as usually different requests run in different threads) takes care for most of that kind of problems, as every method invocation involves new objects run in a separate context.

There are exceptions, though:
- Singleton (global) objects whose any of their operations have side effects
- Other resources (files, etc. ), this is exactly your case.

So in the case of files, I'd ponder these (mutually exclusive) alternatives:

(1) Never write the uploaded file to disk, instead hold it into memory and process it in there (like in byte array). In this case you're leveraging the thread-per-request protection. This one cannot be applied if your files are really big.

(2) Choose very randomized names (like UUID) to write them into a temporary location so their names won't clash if two users upload at the same time.

I'd go with (1) whenever possible.

Best